# Hibernate Interceptor PostLoad

Tags: hibernate, events, orm, interceptor

I have been moving a project from JPA to Hibernate native implementation (got outvoted by team :<).

One of the fabulous things I have to deal with is that @PostLoad does not work with Hibernate native library. So I Googled a bit.

First I looked into EventListeners -> Nope, the Configuration class no longer seems to let you set it. And when I injected it in the cfg file, the listeners still refuse to work.

Okay, next, I looked into Interceptors -> Nope, no post-load. instantiate also doesn't pass in the object itself. How convenient.

And then finally, I looked into LifeCycle -> Wow yes, it has onLoad(), but it passes in the Session and a Serializable Id but no object. Nice.

Anyway, all I want is something that listens for post-load with a handler function called onPostLoad(Object object, yadda yadda yadda). Does anyone have a good suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interceptors do have an `onLoad()` method. Have you checked into that? Its signature looks like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onLoad(Object entity, Serializable id, Object[] state,
        String[] propertyNames, Type[] types) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return super.onLoad(entity, id, state, propertyNames, types);
}
```

Note that if you change a property in the entity, you will have to return true, and return false otherwise (say you are simply counting entities, for example).

If you are using Spring, you will wire your interceptor in like this:

```
<bean id="sessionFactory"       class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="entityInterceptor">
        <bean class="my.company.MyInterceptor"/>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: Actually I am aware of that, but I did not realize that the variables are also passed in. While having to do the initialization myself is annoying, I suppose there's no other way. I still can't believe Hibernate does not have an easy handler for something so rudimentary.

Comment: Well for your case, making your entities implement Lifecycle seems like a better deal. Since it is the entity itself that implements the interface, wouldn't you have the instance anyway (via this)? Or am I missing something in your question?

Comment: Thanks, that works like magic. After all that frustration with those bulky eventlisteners and strangely designed intercepters, I am frankly surprised that lifecycle is such an elegant solution (I thought it works like Interceptors where it is like a handler class instead of something really to just... implement on the entity itself). Solved my problem!

Answer (score 0):

Generally a good idea to name the versions of things you are asking about...

> EventListeners -> Nope, the Configuration class no longer seems to let you set it

So you are using 4.x I assume?  In 4.x EventListeners are part of the services infrastructure added in Hibernate 4.  Take a look at http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/devguide/en-US/html_single/#integrators